# SonarQube with Java application on JDK 7

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using a java application with gradle. I need to build it via jenkins and push the sonar report to sonarqube server. My SonarQube server version is 5.6. My java application is on JDK7.

Is it possible to push the sonar report with this version mismatch.

Comment: use sonar lint for Eclipse.it give the analysis part.

Comment: Could you elaborate what `version mismatch` means?